# What is the best way to debug an app deployed to Kubernetes locally using Docker Desktop?

Tags: c#, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have experience using Docker to develop a relatively complex application.  It is very easy to debug an app using Visual Studio (2019).  I just set docker-compose.yaml as the startup app and start debugging.

Is it possible to debug an application that is published to Kubernetes locally using Docker Desktop? By debug I mean set breakpoints etc? I have spent a few hours Googling this and I have got nowhere and hence the reason for the question.

Please note that I am not asking how to debug an app that is published to Kubernetes in the Cloud e.g. Azure - there are plenty of webpages that explain how to do that.

Comment: Probably, you'll find this helpful: https://espressocoder.com/2019/06/11/getting-started-with-docker-in-visual-studio-2019/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the image uses a Java CMD, include the standard debug JVM arguments ([What are Java command line options to set to allow JVM to be remotely debugged?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/138511/2568649)), then expose the debug port when running a container, and in IDE set up a remote debug session on that port once the container starts up.

Comment: Actually I just saw the C# tag - my answer is probably not relevant - sorry

Answer (score 0):

[Telepresence](https://www.telepresence.io/) may be a very good fit for you.

Using telepresence you can debug your Kubernetes service locally, using your favorite debugging tool. So it doesn't matter where your K8S cluster is.

Take a look on [this](https://www.telepresence.io/tutorials/kubernetes) tutorial to check how it works.

> #### HOW IT WORKS:
>
> Telepresence substitutes a two-way network proxy for your normal pod
>   running in the Kubernetes cluster. This pod proxies data from your
>   Kubernetes environment (e.g., TCP connections, environment variables,
>   volumes) to the local process. The local process has its networking
>   transparently overridden so that DNS calls and TCP connections are
>   routed through the proxy to the remote Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: I am taking about debugging local Kubernetes (enabled in Docker Desktop) using Visual Studio 2019.  I believe your link is more appropriate for Cloud type environments.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Using telepresence you can standardize all your debugging approaches regardless where your K8S cluster is located.

Comment: OK thanks.  Do you know of a tutorial that explains how to use it with Visual Studio 2019 and Kubernetes enabled in Docker Desktop?

Comment: I couldn't find anything specific to VS but have you checked [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/local-debugging/#developing-or-debugging-an-existing-service) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/developing-services-with-k8s) documents?

Answer (score -2):

you can stdout docker logs , use kubectl logs pod_name -n namespace_name

Comment: Is it possible to do this in Visual Studio 2019? (not VS Code).   Is there a webpage that explains how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/DanielBerman/0724195d977f97d68fc2c7bc4a4e0419